# What's the difference between 威厳 and 尊厳?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

What's the difference between [`威{い}厳{げん}`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%A8%81%E5%8E%B3) and [`尊{そん}厳{げん}`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%B0%8A%E5%8E%B3) to mean "dignity"?

From what I can tell, the two seem to be similar, but slightly different. In what ways do the nuances and usages of the two differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First lets get the definitions from a dictionary:

> [尊厳](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/131972/m0u/)：とうとくおごそかなこと。気高く犯しがたいこと。また、そのさま。「人間の―を守る」
>
> [威厳](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/10818/m0u/%E5%A8%81%E5%8E%B3/): 近寄りがたいほど堂々としておごそかなこと

If you look above, both definitions have the phrase `おごそかなこと` in them. This is where they are similar in meaning. The difference is in the first characters `尊` and `威`. Lets think of `尊` as representing "value" and `威` represents "power".

Lets look at some examples:

> 暴力は人間の尊厳を奪う
>
> 個人の尊厳
>
> 犠牲者の尊厳を守る

In the above sentences, you cannot replace `尊厳` with `威厳`. The above sentences talk about something you should respect and uphold. So, `尊厳` is used in phrases talking about rights every human or individual should have, a level of respect, etc. (hence representing "value")

> 親としての威厳を保つ
>
> 国家の威厳を損ねる
>
> 威厳のある顔

The above is talking more about power and influence over others. If a parent does not have `威厳`, then a child is probably not going to listen to them, or if a country doesn't have `威厳` then they probably have to follow the orders from another country and never get their way, etc. (hence representing "power").